# Laravel, "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setReconnector()"

Tags: php, laravel

for some reason this code

```
$results = DB::table('salaries')
            ->join('districts', 'salary_district', '=', 'district_id')
            ->join('companies', 'salary_company', '=', 'company_id')
            ->join('positions', 'salary_position', '=', 'position_id')
            ->select('*')
            ->get();
```

Returns this error in the log file: 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setReconnector()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\salaries\bootstrap\compiled.php:7524

What is causing this? Googling the error gave me nothing.

Comment: try with *composer dump-autoload*